# How do I set older version of Capistrano as default version/gem system wide?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jenkins, capistrano

I'm setting up an environment on a new Ubuntu18.04 server and I need to use Capistrano 3.6.x but when installing using apt-get I continue to pull 3.11.x.

I know I can create gem files for individual apps but I don't want to create Gemfiles for each app in production.

I'd prefer to have Capistrano set at 3.6.x system-wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way - `sudo apt-mark hold <name>`

another way- use gem install instead of apt get and specify the version

Comment: wouldn't `apt-mark hold` require it to already be installed in order to hold a version?

I'll look into the gem install version

Comment: even when I run `sudo apt-get install ruby && gem install capistrano -v 3.6.1` I'm still seeing Capistrano v3.11.0 installed.

Comment: I had both 3.11 and 3.6 installed. Resolved once I uninstalled 3.11 with `gem uninstall capistrano --version 3.11.0`

Thank!